# MySQL update statement getting cut off

Tags: php, mysql

**Disclaimer**

Before trying to close out this question, please understand that I have already post it on wordpress.se.com and even offered an bounty with no answer forth coming.  This lead me to believe maybe the issue was not related to WordPress it self, but some php/mysql quirk that I do not yet understand.  I hope I have provided enough information below for experts in php/mysql to give me some idea what might have went wrong.

[Link to original post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48692/post-content-getting-cut-off-on-blank-space-on-wpdb-update)

The issue I am having is that the update statement

```
UPDATE
    `s_6_posts`
SET
    `post_author` = 9,
    `post_date` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05',
    `post_date_gmt` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05',
    `post_content` = '\n\n\n<div class=\"WordSection1\">\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'>This is a new document</span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'> </span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'>Test Test Test</span></b></p>\n\n</div>\n\n\n',
    `post_content_filtered` = '',
    `post_title` = '',
    `post_excerpt` = '',
    `post_status` = 'draft',
    `post_type` = 'post',
    `comment_status` = 'open',
    `ping_status` = 'open',
    `post_password` = '',
    `post_name` = '',
    `to_ping` = '',
    `pinged` = '',
    `post_modified` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05',
    `post_modified_gmt` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05',
    `post_parent` = 0,
    `menu_order` = 0,
    `guid` = 'https://qa.citivelocity.com/cvauthor/equitywire/?p=230'
WHERE
    `ID` = 230
```

was getting cut off when executed in php (WordPress code base).  The result in the database for the post_content field is

```
<div class="WordSection1">

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";color:red'>This is a new document</span></b></p>

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";color:red'>
```

**Problem**

What is happening here is in

```
<span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";
    color:red'> </span>
```

block, everything after the space between `<span>` tag is cut off.  I have been able to reproduce this issue consistently with other data contain space as well.  It doesn't seem to be a size limitation on the field as the cut off always happened at the space, regardless of the length of the data.

This SQL statement was outputted in the WordPress debug log and I have every reason to belief it is actually the statement being executed.  I ran the same statement through MySQL client (Aqua Data Studio) and the cut off did not happen.

I am running Mysql 5.0.77 with php 5.3 on CentOs.  The tables are MyISAM and collation is utf8_general_ci.

Post table schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `s_posts` (
      `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
      `post_title` text NOT NULL,
      `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
      `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
      `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
      `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
      `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
      `pinged` text NOT NULL,
      `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `post_content_filtered` text NOT NULL,
      `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
      `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
      KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
      KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
      KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Format your SQL properly. There is a long horizontal scroll that gives us headache.

Comment: Are all the other fields following the `post_content` set properly as well?

Comment: Going a little further with Lion's suggestion, make sure it's actualy SQL output from the code - there's probably an improperly escaped quote or something that breaks the query string.

Comment: post the db table schema

Comment: Thanks, i will format the code.  If you scroll back, you will notice that post_content is not the last field on the list.  The statement executes successfully and the fields behind post_content are updated correctly.

Comment: Is `post_content` being cut off or does it include the entire string?

Comment: @MikePurcell See below "Problem".

Comment: Is it possible you have some kind of non-printable or null character in that space that would cause MySQL to stop at that point. If you print the SQL or copy it from a log, it wouldn't have that "hidden" character so that would explain why it works from the other app.

Comment: I view the log using TextPad, which shows non-printable characters.  This thing has been bugging me for a really long time now and I would very much like to find out why.

Comment: Your "problem" is ambiguous, are you saying the data being stored in mysql is cut-off?

Comment: Yes that is the case.  I stated specifically that the page_content field is cut-off.  After the update, if I query to same record, it shows the cut-off.

Comment: Did you verify from the MySQL client that the post_content was cut-off? Also, just out of curiosity, what is your max_allowed_packet setting in MySQL?

Comment: I ran the same statement through MySQL client (Aqua Data Studio) and the cut off did not happen.

Comment: @mongofish, so when you run the SELECT statement through the MySQL client and it's not cut off, then the issue is not with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the code which handles the database interaction (how query is built and executed), but if you `prepare` the string, your data should be inserted/updated in it's entirety as expected.

I ran the string through `PDO::prepare` and resulted in:

```
6774 Query  update fulltext_test set post_content = '\\n\\n\\n<div class=\\\"WordSection1\\\">\\n\\n<p class=\\\"MsoNormal\\\" style=\\\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\\\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\\\"ArialNarrow\\\",\\\"sans-serif\\\";color:red\'>This is a new document</span></b></p>\\n\\n<p class=\\\"MsoNormal\\\" style=\\\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\\\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\\\"ArialNarrow\\\",\\\"sans-serif\\\";color:red\'> </span></b></p>\\n\\n<p class=\\\"MsoNormal\\\" style=\\\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\\\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\\\"ArialNarrow\\\",\\\"sans-serif\\\";color:red\'>Test Test Test</span></b></p>\\n\\n</div>\\n\\n\\n' WHERE id = 1 limit 1
```

Notice all the escaping of the escape characters. I verified that the data was inserted into mysql successfully:

```
mysql> select * from fulltext_test\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    id: 1
    comment: this is a test comment right here 123453432
    trimmed_comments: this 
    post_content: \n\n\n<div class=\"WordSection1\">\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red'>This is a new document</span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red'> </span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red'>Test Test Test</span></b></p>\n\n</div>\n\n\n
```

And the code snippet:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=zzz_test;host=127.0.0.1';

try {
    $dbo = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'pass');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}

$string = '\n\n\n<div class=\"WordSection1\">\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'>This is a new document</span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'> </span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'>Test Test Test</span></b></p>\n\n</div>\n\n\n';

$sql = 'update fulltext_test set post_content = :postContent WHERE id = 1 limit 1;';

$stmt = $dbo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':postContent', $string);

$stmt->execute();
```

So, try to escape the string before executing the query, and you should be golden. For the record, everything is UTF-8; connection, collation etc.

Comment: Mike, looking at my posts.post_content data, it shouldn't be escaped twice.

Comment: It only escapes twice when being added to database, so string is stored in it's entirety. Notice the string as stored in the table, no double escaping.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The text in the field should read `<div class="WordSection">` etc. No visible escaped characters. In other words, it was already escaped.

Comment: Can you post the code which inserts the content into the database? For the record, wasn't the original problem that the string was being cutoff, and now the problem is you don't want escape characters to be inserted?

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm just pointing out the proper format for the posts.post_content column for a WordPress database.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Ahhh my bad, wasn't sure if there was a name change. I think he may have done the escaping manually somewhere which is part of the problem, but I agree, the text should be stored as you indicated.

Comment: @mongofish: Haven't heard any response, were you able to resolve the issue?